# Trying to discretize a continuous signal but I'm trying to plot the regular signal given roots

Tags: matlab, signals

I need to plot out a function based on roots that I can use poly() to get the polynomial for. However, whenever I run the function, it gives me an error. I want to be able to fix the error so I can continue onto my further goals.

I need to plot the function with respect to the domain of time I provide, plot the function with respect to the sampling index nVec multiplied by the sampling rate deltaT, then plot the discrete signal. I am at a stop right now because I cannot plot the continuous signal (the first plot). It consistently gives me an error. I have tried changing the roots (rootsVec) from negative inclusion to purely positive so I can obtain the equation from poly() as well as put the sampling rate for the increment in time but to no avail.

```
    function [tVec,nVec,xVec] = 
    fxNthOrderPolyDTSignal(domainVec,noOfSamples,rootsVec)
    DSIntervals = noOfSamples - 1;
    deltaT = (max(domainVec) - min(domainVec))/DSIntervals;
    %time = input("Please input a specific time within the domain: ");
    nVec = min(domainVec)/deltaT;
    tVec = min(domainVec) + (nVec * deltaT);
    Eqtn = poly(rootsVec);
    x = linspace(domainVec(1),0.5,max(domainVec));
    figure(1)
    plot(Eqtn(x),x)
    figure(2)
    plot(Eqtn,(nVec*deltaT))
    end
```

The expected result is simply a plot of the the signal with the following input arguments: 
domainVec = [-10, 10] (this is the time where the signal exists);

noOfSamples = 30;

rootsVec = [-3, 8] (aka a second order polynomial);

The actual result is the following error: Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. This was the correct answer to my problem. Thank you for your help!

```
function [tVec,nVec,xVec] = 
fxNthOrderPolyDTSignal(domainVec,noOfSamples,rootsVec)
deltaT = (max(domainVec) - domainVec(1))/noOfSamples;
nVec = [0 : noOfSamples];
tVec = [];
for i = nVec
    tVec(end + 1) = min(domainVec) + (i*deltaT);
end
nomial = poly(rootsVec);
xVec = polyval(nomial,tVec);
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(tVec,xVec)
title('x(t)')
subplot(3,1,2)
stem(tVec,xVec)
title('x[n]')
subplot(3,1,3)
stem(tVec,tVec*0)
title('x(nDeltaT)')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, with a proper naming of variables, more Signal Processing style...

With n=10 you will start to see the discretization.

```
function [t,x,dt] = f(tlim,n,p)
%% Function (Press 'Run Section' from here)

% Parameters (Delete these for function to work)
tlim=[-10 10];
n=30;
p=[-3 8];

% Polinomial Coefficients from Roots
a=poly(p);

% Sampling Time
dt=(tlim(2)-tlim(1))/n;

% Evaluate
t=linspace(tlim(1),tlim(2),n)';
x=a(1)*t.^0+a(2)*t.^1+a(3)*t.^2;

% Plot
plot(t,x)
```